# Tag request: reference-question

Tags: discussion, tags

Anton Trunov noted that Stack Exchange site *[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)* has a tag, [`reference-question`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-question).

**Is there a use for a similar tag on Stack Overflow?**

It has the following description:

> Reserved -- shouldn't be used for most new questions. Questions with a broad scope about general methods and concepts, such as proof methods, tools for algorithm analysis or basics of computer architecture. This is not for questions asking for references, i.e. books or articles.

This was motivated by a question on [comparing reals in Standard ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394992/why-cant-i-compare-reals-in-standard-ml?) where a question/answer pair was moved from being a sub-question/answer to its own question for better reference (when marking something as duplicate or when linking to that question/answer in particular).

This practice itself seems very fine; does a tag somehow improve on a sub-community's endorsement of a question? It seems easier to enforce on a smaller Stack Exchange site like *Computer Science*.

Comment: We have them as well, they're called *canonicals* (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510)). They don't have their own tag, though.

Comment: What is the advantage of such a tag? We have generally decided that meta tags are not valuable—i.e., tags that describe the *nature* of a question, rather than the *content* of a question. Why would this one be an exception?

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't know, that's why I'm asking. :)

Comment: You can find popular duplicates (per tag) [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/315074/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures). This is not the same as canonicals, but it comes close (due to the nature of Stack Overflow questions).

Comment: @Glorfindel the same but live is on [/tags/tag/?sort=frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/?sort=frequent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, lets repeat what the tags are for:

> Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Now, what would be the experts that a [reference-question] tag will connect, considering that SO questions can be very disparaged? Not many, I would guess, probably not even a handful. I tried to see exactly how where they used on CS, to check whenever it would be useful on SO, and I find it woefully inappropriate and very redundant.

Of the 22 questions tagged with [reference-question] on CS, 20 appear on the [Frequent questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) tab, 14 of them are the first 14 of the frequent list, then jumps place 15, to continue on until place 18, and then it becomes spotted, which begs the question: Given that we know the criteria for the questions on the frequent tab which is "questions linked to (internally) the most", which should be the criteria for adding this new tag?

If we go by the most frequently asked by inbound links, we have something of the sort, we also have the most viewed, most voted, with the most answers, etc. At this point you have to critically ask yourself "Is this really needed?". My most sensible answer is "no".

Comment: Had I performed this analysis of the CS tag, and thought for a moment about the purpose of tags, I would have agreed with your conclusion before asking the question. Thanks.